# Unable to get any output whatsoever in standalone WordPress script

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a standalone WordPress script.

In it I'm requiring `wp-load.php` so that I can interact with the WordPress installation.

```
include_once '/var/www/html/wp-load.php';
```

I run the script with `php my-script.php` in my bash terminal.

If I `echo` anything before the include, I get output. If I echo anything after the include, I get no output. When I type `echo $?` in bash, I get `0`.

I've tried `fwrite(STDOUT, 'hello');` but that does not work.

I've also tried

```
$stdout = fopen('php://stdout', 'w');
fwrite($stdout, 'foo');
```

and also `error_log('foo', 3, '/tmp/foo.log');`

None of these work.